# Debugging boot performance issues in grub / before kernel logging starts

Tags: boot, grub, performance, boot-loader, debugging

My PC takes a long time booting. I have reason to believe it is caused by delays after grub, but before kernel logging starts (booting takes 30 seconds, but `dmesg` messages have time stamps between `0.00000` - `9.34223`, details in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499832/long-time-spent-between-grub2-menu-before-kernel-boot)).

Are there any ways to debug what's going on? In particular:

- Is there a way to make grub itself more verbose, or keep logs?
- Are there any other processes between grub and the kernel logging that could be taking time? How do I debug those?

I believe the question is not specific to my setup. But just in case, I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 and grub(2)

**EDIT**:

Following a suggestion by  @TooTea, I set the `debug=all` environment variables which produced a lot of messages a la `script/script.c:50 malloc 0x7a9a2ca0` that should not be a problem. Then there is one block of messages that coincide with a 8 seconds delay delay:

```
kern/dl.c:56 Detecting ext2... 
lib/relocator.c:1397 chunks = 0x7a7e0ae0
lib/relocator.c:434 trying to allocate in ...-... aligned ... size ...
lib/relocator.c:1198 allocated: ...+...
lib/relocator.c:1409 allocated .../...
lib/relocator.c:1410  chunks = 0x7a7e0ae0
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the actual performance problem? If so, how? I'm seeing the exact same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I did not

Answer (score 6):

This is certainly not a full answer to my own question but might be useful for others landing here while investigating similar issues.

The GRUB manual suggests to use the `debug` environment variable, either with `debug=all` or with a comma/whitespace list of facility names. It then says:

> Consult source for more details.

I was not able to find a list of potential names online.
So for future reference I pulled a list of those names from the current github repository coreos/grub, hoping that this might be useful for me and others in the future. Of course, without further investigating the source this is of limited use, but still might be a good starting point.

```
name                frequency in source
acpi                |||||
affs                |
ahci                ||
appleload           |
arcdisk             ||
archelp             ||
ata                 ||
atkeyb              ||
biosdisk            ||
bsd                 ||||
btrfs               ||
cache               ||
cbfs                |
chain               |||
crypt               ||
cryptodisk          ||
datetime            |
devalias            ||
disk                |||||
diskfilter          ||
dl                  ||||||||
dns                 ||
drivemap            ||
efi                 ||
efidisk             ||
efiemu              ||||||||||||||
ehci                ||
elf                 ||
exfat               |
expand              ||
fat                 |
fb                  ||
fdt                 |
fixvideo            ||
font                ||
fs                  ||
geli                ||
gpt                 ||||
hostdisk            |||||
init                |||||
jpeg                |
keystatus           ||
lexer               |
linux               |||||||||||||
loader              |||||||
luks                ||
memdisk             ||
mm                  ||
mmap                |||||
modules             ||
multiboot_loader    |||||
nativedisk          ||
net                 ||||||||||
ohci                ||
partition           ||||||
pata                ||
play                ||
reiserfs_tree       ||
relocator           |||
scripting           ||
scsi                ||
serial              ||
smbios              ||
syslinux            ||
tftp                ||
tga                 ||
ubootdisk           ||
uhci                ||
usb                 ||||||
usb_keyboard        ||
usbms               ||
video               |||||||
xen                 |||||||||
xen_loader          ||
xfs                 ||
xnu                 ||||||
zfs                 |||||
```

So for example you can write

```
set debug=linux,video,fs
```

into your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to reduce the debug verbosity of GRUB and only show debug messages for those facilities

Comment: Thanks for the info. Apparently luks and luks2 are not logged properly. So right now it is not properly possible to debug their output as for example here: https://github.com/rhboot/grub2/blob/4f9d3f4f8d7866c69e52ba7d81562daea38b22e6/grub-core/disk/luks.c#L211

I dunno why this happens, since cryptsetup works fine, but gives no proper info.

Answer (score 5):

As you can probably imagine, the handover between GRUB and Linux involves some really intricate low-level steps, so there's no room for advanced tracing or logging. Fortunately, that shouldn't be a problem as there's also no room for any extended stalls in that code. You can get a really detailed trace of all the preparatory steps in GRUB by setting the [`debug` environment variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#debug).

It is, however, more likely that whatever delays you see happen after the control is transferred to the Linux kernel. Normally, you can't see the log messages before the console is initialized. Also, as you have noted, all the timestamps are zero until the timekeeping subsystem is initialized, so it is impossible to figure out the timing later.

Fortunately, you can use the `earlyprintk` boot option to make the kernel actually print the log messages somewhere, so that you can follow them in real time and see where the delay occurs. `earlyprintk` can be directed to various destinations, but the most relevant for usual (physical) machines will be `serial`, `vga` (old-school console), or `efi`. Make sure that your kernel is built with the appropriate config options (`CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK*`).

Comment: thanks! is there another useful specification for `debug` than `debug=all` if gives me a lot of messages that seem to be not problematic, but make it harder to see what's causing the delay, even/espacially with `pager=1`

Comment: @sheß `linux` may be the most relevant (OS-specific interface/handover bits), see the GRUB source for others