# Troubleshooting extreme boot time on Linux

Tags: linux, boot, dual-boot, boot-loader, troubleshooting

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask such tech support related questions, but this definitely seems to be a Linux issue or at least regarding the way Linux interacts with my hardware.

I have a desktop PC built out of a HP Z800 Workstation, and it might be relevant that the system is *not* UEFI-capable, so all operating systems use legacy BIOS and MBR partition schemes.

I am usually dual booting Windows 10 and a Linux distribution (currently Linux Mint 20.2, but this issue exists for *all* distros that I have tried, including Debian 11, Ubuntu 20.04-21.10, Fedora 33-35, OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and Arch Linux).

Since I am a mostly non-technical user, I am not sure what the proper terminology is but to be able to correctly describe my issue I have to separate the boot process into three stages (these are my own terminology and my conflict with existing ones which I am not aware of!):

- Stage 1: The part that starts with pressing the power button and ends with getting to the bootloader (GRUB2).
- Stage 2: The part that starts with getting to the bootloader and ends when the actual OS starts booting, i.e. when I get console/systemd messages, the plymouth screen etc.
- Stage 3: The part that starts with the end of Stage 2 end ends when the OS is fully booted and I am on the display manager.

The problem is that Stage 2 takes an insanely long time. So once I get to the bootloader and select (or autoselects) a Linux entry, the screen goes completely blank (based on the distro there might be a flashing prompt here, on Mint it is completely blank but eg. on Fedora I usually get a flashing prompt), the system idles here for an extremely long time (*I have measured about 1 minute 44 secs last time*), and then Stage 3 begins.

Since Stage 3 goes down without an issue, I am not sure how to troubleshoot this. For example systemd-analyze gives `Startup finished in 16.129s (kernel) + 2.863s (userspace) = 18.993s  graphical.target reached after 2.120s in userspace`, which seems normal to me and definitely does not account for the 1 minute+ nothingness between the bootloader and the OS starting to boot.

Further information:

- Windows *does not* behave this way. If I select the Windows 10 entry in the bootloader it starts the boot process instantly (even if fast startup is turned off).
- It did not always behave this way. I am not sure when the behaviour started (probably about a year or so ago), and I think I did a complete reinstallation of both operating systems on the PC, as in I wiped all hard disks clean and installed both W10 and a Linux distro from scratch. But nothing extraordinary happened that could make think of any root cause for this issue.
- Aside from small differences (like the flashing prompt I mentioned before), all Linux distros that I have tried since then behave the same way. I did not measure the boot times for different distros for variance though. But in each case the wait time is far more than it would be appropriate and it is always the same, between Stage 2 and Stage 3.
- My PC has three hard disks, two SSDs and one spinning HDD. I usually use one SSD for Windows C:, another SSD for the Linux / partition and the spinning HDD for the Linux /home and Windows D: partitions. I have experimented with writing MBR boot code during the installation of Linux to each of these disks and the same issue happens in all cases. So it seems that which is the boot disk is immaterial.

I do not necessarily expect a magical fix, but as I have said I have absolutely no clue how to even start troubleshooting this, as during the wait time no feedback is given to me, and this problem is very difficult to search for (eg. searching for slow boot times usually assumes a Stage 3 issue).

EDIT:

- I have removed `quiet` and `splash` and added `systemd.show_status=yes` to the boot parameters. The issue remains, i.e. there is minute+ wait time before *any* message appears.
- The output of `dmesg | grep command` is `[    0.064784] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-38-generic root=UUID=78354078-8fcd-4223-8fb0-9137207cb415 ro systemd.show_status=yes`.
- About LED lights: During the "wait time" the green light next to my power button was constantly emitting light with no flashes. This is the only LED light I see on my chassis.
- The output of `fdisk -l` and `lsblk` are pasted below:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 447,13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: CT480BX500SSD1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00a879e5

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    104447    102400    50M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          104448 936654957 936550510 446,6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       936656896 937697279   1040384   508M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE


Disk /dev/sdb: 1,84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZRX-00D
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfc1366de

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048 2833283071 2833281024  1,3T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       2833283072 3907028991 1073745920  512G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdc: 223,58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x143a208b

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1       452857856 468860927  16003072  7,6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc2  *         2048 452857855 452855808  216G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

and

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 447,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    50M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 446,6G  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0   508M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   1,3T  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0   512G  0 part /Storage
sdc      8:32   0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   7,6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdc2   8:34   0   216G  0 part /
```

Comment: In principle, what GRUB is doing at that stage it is reading kernel and initramfs, unpacking them and giving a control. Do you notice any media access indication during that time (i.e. LED blinking)? Could it be your Linux boot partition id misaligned? Show us your partitioning (at least, `fdisk -l /dev/sd[abc]`, also `lsblk`). Show us your kernel command line (`dmesg | grep comand`). Try to remove any occurence of `quiet` from kernel command line and GRUB configuration to see verbose messages. Expect to give additional information afterwards.

Comment: Remove `quiet` and any arguments which hide boot progress from the boot arguments, e.g. `splash` or `rhgb`, please and check if you start seeing kernel messages immediately or there's still the same delay. If it's the latter it could indicate that GRUB is having troubles reading the kernel image and initial ramdisk. Also add `systemd.show_status=yes`. Also check this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502931/debugging-boot-performance-issues-in-grub-before-kernel-logging-starts/503344

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for the response, the question has been updated accordingly.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for the response, the question has been updated accordingly.

Comment: Start debugging GRUB using the question I linked to in my previous comment. Not sure about `earlyprintk` - this option could have been renamed recently.

Comment: Are all UUIDs correct in fstab? Often a reinstall reformats a partiiton and then you may have mis-match of UUIDs. `lsblk -f` &  `cat /etc/fstab` Other issues: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: 1) Can you confirm what the LED behavior means, based on what it does at other times? 2) What's the command that GRUB uses? You can see it by pressing 'e' while the GRUB menu is visible. 3) Does disconnecting the two disks not required for the boot process have any impact?

Comment: Show a `blkid` and at least an *active* section of `grub.cfg` (or the whole `grub.cfg`, but that may be huge). This is what it needs to be checked for UUIDs correspondence and understand GRUB behaviour. Which disk is the boot drive (which is selected in the BIOS to boot from), where is *grub* installed, and which one has the partition where the grub modules and grub.cfg are residing, is that `sdc`? What if you install grub onto it, then remove all disks except this one and try to boot? What if you just select it in BIOS as the boot one?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Sorry, I have meant to update OP, but forgot to do so. Basically I managed to fix the problem by moving the Linux root partition to the other SSD. This is kinda inelegant since I still don't know what caused the issue, but at least its not doing it anymore. This does make any further attempts to diagnose the issue impossible as my setup is much different now. I will update OP soon.

Comment: I was close :) I still think there was some version disrepancy between grub installed in the MBR and grub files located in /boot/i386-pc/... or whathever you have. Also, I suggest you to make a self-answer out of this and accept it as a soluton, for the question to be marked as solved for anybody who'll encounter this in the future.