# Inconsistent bootloader times after grub, before kernel

Tags: kernel, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

EDIT:

I've narrowed down some specific processes- the format is

```
[good boot
vs
bad boot]

[8.154559] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[8.335203] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
vs
[8.481411] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[10.642746] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
+2 seconds
Note: I've checked the UUIDs on fstab and they match

[8.398891] systemd[1]: Hostname set to <frink>.
[8.526727] systemd[1]: Queued start job for default target Graphical Interface.
vs
[10.991973] systemd[1]: Hostname set to <frink>.
[12.971349] systemd[1]: Queued start job for default target Graphical Interface.
+2 seconds

[8.595713] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[8.608930] systemd-journald[422]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
vs
[13.136621] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[13.768849] input: Intel HID events as /devices/platform/INTC1070:00/input/input9
+0.5 seconds

No entry for name="man_groff"
vs
[14.765699] audit: type=1400 audit(1677744482.483:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=779 comm="apparmor_parser"
[15.630003] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
+1 second

[17.822488] r8169 0000:03:00.0: invalid VPD tag 0x00 (size 0) at offset 0; assume missing optional EEPROM
[22.643689] wlo1: authenticate with 20:47:ed:48:3d:13
vs
[11.254521] r8169 0000:03:00.0: invalid VPD tag 0x00 (size 0) at offset 0; assume missing optional EEPROM
[13.238764] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
+3 seconds
```

Any ideas whats creating the above deltas ?

On some occasions I get a bootup time of 20 seconds and then the next day it would be 25-30 seconds, it's not so much the time that's a bother but the fact that my system is doing something different on each boot especially when the additional time seems to be coming from the bootloader.

```
'good' boot:
Startup finished in 10.387s (firmware) + 4.630s (loader) + 7.083s (kernel) + 2.650s (userspace) = 24.752s 
graphical.target reached after 2.647s in userspace

'bad' boot:
Startup finished in 11.405s (firmware) + 14.686s (loader) + 8.116s (kernel) + 2.945s (userspace) = 37.153s 
graphical.target reached after 2.942s in userspace
```

dmesg, systemd-blame, systemd-critical-chain etc are all very similar. I suspect this is because the delay is occurring before the kernel is even loaded.

I followed this thread:
[Debugging boot performance issues in grub / before kernel logging starts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502931/debugging-boot-performance-issues-in-grub-before-kernel-logging-starts)

and added 'debug=all' to my  grub config but it took ~10 minutes for the all the messages to be printed so it wasn't possible to track the issue,  'debug=linux' prints no messages at all

This issue is very intermittent. What I've found is if I restart or shutdown and start up again in a short amount of time I get the 'good' boot. If I have the computer off, say over night, or off a few hours during the day I'm more likely to see the 'bad' boot. This is without touching the dual booted win 10 OS.
There are no BIOS/bootloader/kernel error messages during the boot phase.

The setup is SSD/Intel i5 12th gen/ kubuntu 22.04 / kernel 5.15.0-58-generic- dual booted with win 10 (fast boot disabled)

Any ideas? I really want to avoid going distro hoping as I enjoy the setup otherwise. Thanks

Comment: I can only think of SSD dying. Have you tried updating BIOS?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov BIOS is up to date, SSD is < 1 year old but I think more importantly this delay never happens on the window boot. Thanks for your input

Comment: This still looks like a HW issue but I have no idea what it is. GRUB is deterministic, it should take the same amount of time to load the kernel and initrd. Probably it tries to enumerate something which is failing or works intermittently. Have you got any USB drives plugged in? Can you unplug everything and test again?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: strangely it got even worse with no USB devices connected and removal of the second monitor: "Startup finished in 9.135s (firmware) + 36.215s (loader) + 7.566s (kernel) + 11.000s (userspace) = 1min 3.917s 
graphical.target reached after 10.978s in userspace" Thanks again for your help

Comment: It could be worse, is this now reproducible and repetitive?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It's not, but I may have found a correlation. When I shutdown(by pressing the power button)  it sometimes takes a very long time to shutdown i.e. you see the logo when most of the time it shutdowns in a few seconds. After a long shutdown it has a long boot. I've just had a look and there doesn't seem to be a way of logging shutdown, but why would one affect the other? unless it's just a red hearing

Comment: What does that time labeled "*loader*" actually represents ? I'd be surprised it is the time taken by the boot loader for its operations since the kernel is totally unaware of what happened before it started executing and therefore the time spent on this.

Comment: @MC68020, I believe it is the bootloader time, the kernel doesn't have to record it, the time value could just be passed to the kernel as a parameter

Comment: I've added some detailed breakdowns in the edit

Comment: OK! Managed to find the answer I was looking for : *"Loader time, is the time GRUB spends on passing control to system (i.e. going to /boot/grub, displaying grub menu, selecting default boot option or the time you take to scroll and select desired menu entry, charging modules, locating and placing in root and locating linux and initrd)